# Is it possible to return a message to Kafka Topic as "unread" message?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm building an Spark Streaming program that i want that it read certain messages and return they as "unread" to the topic if the message could not be processed by the program.

My intention is that the program eventually read the message again and try to process it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "return" a record to the original topic, it'll be appended to the end of the topic, and therefore consumed again on the next poll.

This will cause an infinite consumption loop (until whatever condition that put the record back is no longer true)

What you're asking for seems to be a "dead-letter-queue", which is implemented with different topics, not the original. As for how to process that in Spark, you'd probably have to maintain some `Try` object (Scala), or other boolean type, that knows if a particular event had been processed successfully; then `filter` that out before writing to any downstream systems.

For example a dataframe with this schema that you'd filter/drop the third column before producing

```
topic - string
value - bytes
hasError - boolean
```

Comment: Not really in the spirit of things.

Comment: @theblue ? I was pointing out that its "possible" but requires some work

Comment: I think u get my point. Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not possible  if you think of Kafka offsetting.